# Get value of total coverage percentage from coverage.py using a regular expression (REGEX)

Tags: sed, grep, pytest, coverage.py

This question is basically on how to use regular expressions but I couldn't find any answer to it in a lot of very closely related questions.

I create coverage reports in a gitlab pipeline using [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) and [py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) which look like the following piped into a file like `coverage37.log`:

```
-------------- generated xml file: /builds/utils/foo/report.xml --------------
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.7.11-final-0 -----------
Name                          Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------------------------
foo/tests/bar1.py                52      0   100%
...
foo/tests/bar2.py                 0      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                           431      5    99%
======================= 102 passed, 9 warnings in 4.35s ========================
```

Now I want to create a badge for the total coverage i.e. here the 99% value and only get number (99) in order to assign it to a variable. This variable can then be used to create a flexible coverage badge using the [anybadge](https://github.com/jongracecox/anybadge) package.

My naive approach would be something like:

```
COVERAGE_SCORE=$(sed -n 'what to put here' coverage37.log)
echo "Coverage is $COVERAGE_SCORE"
```

Note that I know that gitlab, github, etc. offer specific functionalities to create badges automatically. But I want to create it manually in order to have more control and create the badge per branch.

Any hints are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to use `awk` here:

```sh
cov_score=$(awk '$1 == "TOTAL" {print $NF+0}' coverage37.log)
```

Here `$1 == "TOTAL"` matches a line with first word as `TOTAL` and `print $NF+0` prints number part of last field.

Answer (score 5):

rather than get approximate values from non-machine-readable outputs you'd be best to use coverage's programmatic apis, either `coverage xml` or `coverage json`

here's an example using the json output (note I send it to `/dev/stdout`, by default it goes to `coverage.json`)

```
$ coverage json -q -o /dev/stdout | jq .totals.percent_covered
52.908756889161054
```

there's even more information there if you need it:

```
$ coverage json -q -o /dev/stdout | jq .totals
{
  "covered_lines": 839,
  "num_statements": 1401,
  "percent_covered": 52.908756889161054,
  "missing_lines": 562,
  "excluded_lines": 12,
  "num_branches": 232,
  "num_partial_branches": 7,
  "covered_branches": 25,
  "missing_branches": 207
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I have missed the JSON option and will look into it! :-)

Comment: This returns seemingly valid json, but also `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column x`. When I combine it with `-R` it shows this string at the end: `Wrote JSON report to /dev/stdout`. How can I suppress that?

Comment: it seems to require `-q` now -- probably a regression in coverage -- probably worth opening an issue if you're up to it

Answer (score 0):

Also if you dont want to store it in a file for some reason, you can do
`cov_score=$(coverage report | awk '$1 == "TOTAL" {print $NF+0}')`